Proof that $dv=\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_i} dx_i$
Let $v$ a diferentiable vector field in $\Bbb R ^n$ and $v= \sum a_i e_i$, It is not clear to me why
$$dv=\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_i} dx_i$$
Related to this i know that
$$d f = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i.$$
Are these properties deduced in the same way? or are they each different?
To prove the desired I suppose I could take the matrix of the partial derivatives of the vector field and apply to it the vectors of the canonical basis, but I don't see it at all clear the truth. Any suggestion?
Remark:If I try to make $v$ a differentiable form and apply the exterior differential, by means of the canonical isomorphism $dx_i \sim e_i$, I would get something like $dv= \sum d a_i \wedge dx_i$.

Exterior differentiation works on antisymmetric exterior differential forms, and your vector field $v$ is not such, though you can convert it to one if you have a basis (frame field), which you seem to have ($e_i$).

I was thinking of using the canonical isomorphism such that $dx_i \sim e_i$ and applying the exterior differential $dv=\sum da_i \wedge dx_i$, but this would lead me to the result I want?

Your formula is incorrect. For example if $n=2$, it is not the case that $$dv = \frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1},dx_1 + \frac{\partial a_2}{\partial d_2},dx_2. $$

It is unclear what your goal is here. You can indeed define the differential of a vector field in the way you want, but it will not be invariant under a change of coordinates, not even a linear one.

You're using the de Rahm derivative or exterior derivative $d$ in the wrong setting. This operator takes $k$-forms to $k+1$-forms. So since in your second example $f$ is a $0$-form, this is correct.
A vector field is kind of dual to a $1$-form. The de Rahm differential of a $1$ form is dual to the curl. So you should actually be using the curl of the vector field here and it has the same exact meaning as what you were getting at.
